# Heep needed with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I face a problem with the str_replace function, see the code below :

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM zakov WHERE chnt='$atd_nad'";
$str   = str_replace("Example.com_", "","$query");
$result = mysql_query($str) or die('Errant query:  '.$str);
```

What I want is to replace the word " Example.com_ " with nothing "" but it did not work for me ! I do not know why.
In the row 'title' you can find something like this " Example.com_nameofsmthng "
So what I want is to keep just the word "nameofsmthng" and also to keep the begining of each word of it in capital letter to have finally somethin like "NameOfSmthng"

Comment: I don't see `Example.com_` anywhere in `$query`, unless it was in `$atd_nad` (can you show us what's in `$atd_nad`?).  Are you trying to remove `Example.com_` from the query or from the result?

Comment: Are you trying to replace text in the query or in the results?

Comment: Post a complete example of the code with the "Example.com_". Your `$query` doesn't have that in it so there's nothing to replace.

Comment: @Rocket - "Example.com_" is situated in title row, and I'm trying to remove Example.com_ from the result, because the result is a json page.

Comment: @Zikooz: You need to get the result first before you can modify it.

Comment: @Rocket: How can I do it ? the result is shown in a json page.

Comment: @Zikooz: Do the `str_replace` after you run the query and before you make it into JSON.

Comment: @Rocket: Can I post the full code here ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to post the full code.  In the loop where you retrieve the results (or the loop where you output them if it's separate), just do the replace there.  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $title = str_replace("blah", "", $row['title']); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$atd_nad = 'Foobar Example.com_nameofsmthng Bazbat';
$query   = 'SELECT title FROM zakov WHERE chnt="' . $atd_nad . '"';
$str     = str_replace('Example.com_', '', $query);
echo $str; // SELECT title FROM zakov WHERE chnt="Foobar nameofsmthng Bazbat"
```

This works fine. [Try it quickly](http://writecodeonline.com/php/). My assumption is that you mistyped $atd_nad or the value is incorrect.

Comment: Even though this is preferable, it won't change anything so I don't think it's the answer.

Comment: `str_replace("Example.com_", "","$query");` should really be `str_replace("Example.com_", "",$query);`.  There's no need to put `$query` in double quotes.

Comment: Do you mean for performance reasons hafichuk?  Because if so, that's not even worth the bother :p.  Also, while I'm being picky, I feel like this answer should have been a comment, not an answer.  "It works for me!" isn't exactly an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not worked for me !
the Example.com_ is situated in 'title' row.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: hmm i think I misunderstood the example your trying to replace the string in the query string instead of the database?

---

You could make mysql do the replacement for you which should be faster then making php do it.

```
$query = "SELECT REPLACE(title, 'Example.com_', '') as newtitle FROM zakov WHERE chnt='$atd_nad'";
$resultset = mysql_query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);  
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $result['newtitle'];
```

Or you could replace all occurrences in the database with an update and then just select the title.

```
UPDATE zakov SET title = REPLACE(title, 'Example.com_', '');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would not like to replace in DB, I would like just to replace in result.

Comment: If you need to replace the result from the database my first example does this inside your query. Giving you newtitle as the title outwith example.com_

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = str_replace("something", "", $row['title']);
}
```

Is what I believe you're looking for.  Your code is trying to replace it in the query, which doesn't make sense.  You need to replace it in the actual records.  This will replace "something" with "".  Alternatively, if you've already stored them in an an array or something you would just loop over the array and do the replacement.  Basically: operate on the records, not on the query.

Comment: Still did not work for me ! :(
Please see this post to more understand :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423156/issue-with-the-str-replace-function

Comment: The theory in my answer should be easily applicable.  Please don't take this the wrong way, but we're here to help with specific problems, not teach you PHP.

Comment: Yes.  What I've written is a 2 second adaptation to fit that page.  $post['title'] = str_replace('...', '...', $post['title']);